# ef codefirst Sum of childtable property

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first

I have a simple EF CodeFirst model that I am using in an MVC3 project, I have scaffolded controllers for Order and Basket.

```
    public class Order
    {

    public int OrderID { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    [DisplayName("When")]
    public DateTime DateOccurred { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Basket> Baskets { get; set; }

    public decimal Total
    {
        get
        {
            return Baskets.Sum(b => b.Price);
        }
    }
}

public class Basket
{
    public int BasketID { get; set; }
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public decimal  Price  { get; set; }
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to use Total as a property within the Order class.

With this implementation, ef will throw an error as soon as a Order is created without a Basket.

Am I going about this in completely the wrong way or is this a simple tweak that I have overlooked???

Comment: Forgot to say that the error is "{"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: source"}".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And if there is not any record of type "Basket", that will throws a cost-error; you can use this code:

```
public class Order{

    public int OrderID { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    [DisplayName("When")]
    public DateTime DateOccurred { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Basket> Baskets { get; set; }

    private decimal? _total;
    public decimal Total{
        get{
            if(_total.HasValue)
                return _total.Value;
            if(this.Baskets == null){
                // retrive Baskets from db, for example:
                this.Baskets = MyRepository.GetBasketsFor(this.OrderId);
            }
            _total = (Baskets.Sum(b => (decimal?) b.Price)) ?? 0;
            return _total.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

but in this way, you must fetch all Baskets from db to calculate sum!!! you can create a Repository-method to do this; for example:

```
private decimal? _total;
public decimal Total{
    get{
        if(!_total.HasValue)
            _total = (MyRepository.GetBasketsTotalFor(this.OrderId)) ?? 0;
        return _total.Value;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class MyRepository{
    static public decimal? GetBasketsTotalFor(int orderId){
        var total = context.Baskets
                               .Where(b => b.OrderId == orderId)
                               .Sum(b => (decimal?) b.Price);
        return total;
    }
}
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure from your description but I guess your problem is that new entity has `Baskets == null`. Just try to add default constructor:

```
public Order()
{
    Baskets = new List<Basket>();
}
```